# Translation in a block class

Tags: blocks, ee-1.13, localisation, ce-1.8.0.0, helper

I have a question about translation in block classes. In phtml files, `$this->__()` (A) is used to translate (or at least most commonly that I've seen). In Mage block classes, `Mage::helper('helpername')->__()` (B) is commonly used, but I've seen people use `$this->__()` in block classes, as well.

Whether it's `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::__()` or `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract::__()`, it doesn't effectivelty matter for now, as they are identical functions (EE 1.13).

**Question 1**

But which is more proper? I understand that this could be somewhat opinion-based, but to be *more* future-resistant, I would think using the helper is more proper.

**Question 2**

Is there a particular reason the functions defined in block classes use the helper's method, whereas the template uses the block's method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to use `Mage::helper('somehelper')->__('...')` because that way I'm sure the translation is done using the specified language file.
You can avoid issues in this case when you rewrite core classes.
Let's say for example you rewrite some block from the catalog module.

If you use in your new block `$this->__()` then Magento will try to use the translation file for your new module. This can lead to trouble.

But there are 2 options here.
*Option 1.*
use `Mage::helper('catalog')->__('...')`

*Option 2.*
add in your new block class this method

```
public function getModuleName() {
    return 'Mage_Catalog';
}
```

This will make `$this->__()` use the `Mage_Catalog` module for translation.

For controllers that doesn't work. You need to add

```
protected function _getRealModuleName(){
    return 'Mage_Catalog';
}
```

But this second option can lead to troubles also, because you may add in your new block texts that don't exist in the `Mage_Catalog.csv` file.

Hence I say using `Mage::helper('somehelper')->__('...')` is safer.

As for templates using `$this->__()` here is my opinion.
Not sure if it's true or not.

In theory a template can be used by multiple blocks from different modules. (although it rarely happens). using `$this->__()` gives you the opportunity to translate the same template in the same language but get different results depending on the module that is using that template.
Sorry but I don't have an example for this. I've never used it like that.